# Add a new line with specific pattern before a matched pattern in Notepad++

Tags: python, regex

I have a csv file and I would like to reform it.  I like to add a new line with "M19" before every line with characters "M06".

Before:

```
T40400010
M06
(T40400010, 5.0MM SOLID CARBIDE REAMER - 6FL)
```

After reforming:

```
T40400010
M19
M06
(T40400010, 5.0MM SOLID CARBIDE REAMER - 6FL)
```

I am planning to solve this using regular expression in python, but i also i open to other solutions.   Thanks.

Comment: Your example is showing `M19` inserted *before* the line with `M06`. Which is it? You have tagged this Python but have Notepad++ in the title. Again: Which is it?

Comment: I have a file in Notepad ++, and I would like to edit it with python following the pattern that add a new line with "M19" before each "M06".

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
import re 

with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'^M06$', line):
            print('M19')
        print(line)
```

Prints:

```
T40400010
M19
M06
(T40400010, 5.0MM SOLID CARBIDE REAMER - 6FL)
```

If you want the `M19` after the `M06` just move the `print(line)` above the `if re.search(r'^M06$', line):` rather than below.

---

If you want to have the effect of 'editing' the file, and the file is a reasonable size (ie, easily fits in memory) you can do:

```
import re 

with open(fn) as f:
    data=re.sub(r'^(M06)$', r'M19\n\1', f.read(), flags=re.M)       

with open(fn, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

---

If you have a file larger than what you want in memory, you can do:

```
import re, tempfile, shutil

with open(fn, 'r') as f_in, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as f_out:
    tmp_name=f_out.name
    for line in f_in:   
        if re.search(r'^M06$', line):
            print('M19\n',end='', file=f_out)   
        print(line,end='', file=f_out)  

shutil.move(tmp_name, fn)
```

Comment: Thank you. And instead of printing the file, is there a way for me to directly edit the file?

Comment: Yes. You would open a second file for writing. 'print' to that. Then rename the new file the same as the old one to overwrite it. This is the same effect as editing the file. There is no in place editing in Python (or really any program; they all do it the same way.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ buildin search+replace dialog (Strg+H for me).

Search for the regex `^M06$` and replace it with `M19\r\nM06` (use `\n` if on unix, `\r\n` is windows).

Make sure to choose the `Regular expression` option.

If you really want to have a newline between those two, double up on `\r\n`

[image: Search and replace dialog]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Notepad++ by doing a search with this expression:

```
^(M06)$
```

And replacing it with:

```
M19\n\1
```

The `\n` character represents a new line, and `\1` represents the reference to the "M06" value in the brackets of the regular expression. Anything in the brackets (in this case, "M06") will be captured, and returned as \1.

The reason I used the reference to a capture group, instead of just replacing it with "M19\nM06", is because you may want to alter the expression to find more data. For example, if there is other data on the M06 line, you might want to look for an expression like this:

```
^(.*M06.*)$
```

**Edit**: Patrick beat me to the answer. I'm leaving this up, just for the addition of the capture group.